# Why would SSDT show some minor changes for certain tables only?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools

In my .sqlproj project I have a number of SQL database tables which have columns with default constraints such as:

```
 CREATE TABLE TableName
(
-- Some other columns defined too
[State] TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
)
```

When I run SSDT *schema compare* of the project against the production database the following happens. Some tables like the one above are reported having no differences and one is reported to have the following difference.

The comparison tool says that the project has this (and that's true and it's also true for all other tables):

```
-- Single braces around zero
[State] TINYINT DEFAULT (0) NOT NULL
```

but the database has this:

```
-- Double braces around zero
[State] TINYINT DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL
```

This is annoying because it causes a lot of useless changes being reported. It is even more annoying because I have something like ten tables with such column definition but differences are only reported for one table only.

I tried to open SSMS and right click the table in the production database and *Script table as*, *CREATE To new window* and it yields the following line in the creation script:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName]
  ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [State]
```

and the very same thing is being emitted for all the tables but the difference is only reported for one table in the comparison.

How do I address this? How do I know why this table is *special* and the difference is only reported for this table only?

Comment: Well, this is weird. You could look in `sys.default_constraints`. Default constraint expressions are parsed and stored in a canonical form, which is why the parentheses are added. If you do `DEFAULT 0` in a script, it gets stored as `((0))`, and that's what SSMS reports -- but then, it's not clear how it gets to `(0)` in other circumstances (you'd expect the extra parens to always be stripped), or why the comparison wouldn't always take this into account.

Comment: Could you try with the latest version of SSDT? Please always use the latest version of SSDT and SSMS to have the best experience with Azure SQL Database.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old problem with SSDT that was fixed - now when SSDT imports the model from the database which it uses to generate the list of differences, the wrapping parenthesis are removed and the expression that is left is compared so first of all download the latest SSDT.

I have checked and the problem is in a version 12.0 of SSDT and fixed in 14.0 so the fix is somewhere between there.

I would just set all of your defaults to (( )) - either do it manually or do a compare from your database back to your project, this will do two things firstly it will mean you don't get these annoying additional things and secondly it will make the compare a little bit faster.

If the version stored in the SSDT project doesn't have two ('s and )'s wrapping the expression SSDT goes through an additional step of removing the ('s from the script that is retrieved from the database *but* if you have (( x )) then SSDT knows that the database will also have (( x )) so it doesn't have to remove the extra brackets.

So, 1 - upgrade, 2 - put them right.

ed